# How to solve my unit test issue in my case

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I am trying to write a unit test for my codes and I need some guidance.

I have something in my file like

```
//inside my 'testCtrl' I have
$scope.calculateTime = function() {
    var date = new Date();
    $scope.currentYear = date.getFullYear();
}

$scope.calculateLastYear = function() {
    $scope.currentYear = $scope.currentYear - 1;
}
```

my test file.

```
describe('Controller: testCtrl', function(){
    beforeEach(module('myApp'));
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootscope_) {
        scope._$rootScope.$new();

        testCtrl = _$controller_('testCtrl', {
            $scope:scope 
        })
    })

    //for some reason, every tests I write below are passed even  
    //though it should fail

      it('should get the last year'), function() {
            expect(scope.currentYear).toBe('text here….') //<-- it should fail but   
                                                          //it passes
      };
})
```

I am not sure how to write the test to check the `calculateLastYear` function and I don't know why my `expect(scope.currentYear).toBe('text here….')` passed. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: beofreEach should be beforeEach

Comment: bracket in the wrong place. it('should get the last year'),

Comment: not sure why this is off topic - there was a typo - but there was also an issue with the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your spec syntax is incorrect. It should be this (excuse the pun):

```
it('should get the last year', function() {
            expect(scope.currentYear).toBe('text here….');
});
```

Calculate last year spec:

```
  it('should get the last year', function() {
    $scope.currentYear = 2015;
    $scope.calculateLastYear();
    expect($scope.currentYear).toEqual(2014);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed it. Is it possible that you can help me to write the test for the calculateLastYear function? +1

Comment: it('should calculate last year', function() {
    $scope.currentYear = 2015;
    $scope.calculateLastYear();
    expect($scope.currentYear).toEqual(2014);
  });